# Why, when I print a derefrenced pointer in main that points to a variable declared in a function, does it not print junk memory?

Tags: go

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func point(x int) *int {
    y := x
    return &y//Shouldn't this be deallocated
}

func main() {
    x := 10
    pointer := point(x)
    fmt.Println(*pointer)
}
```

Shouldn't the memory for Y be junk after the function has been called?
Why is it that my program still outputs 10.

Comment: "Shouldn't the memory for Y be junk after the function has been called?" No, of corse not. Go is not C. Please read some introduction material (e.g. the Tour of Go) and the language spec.

Answer (score 3):

Go compiler performs escape analysis for variables and decides whether to allocate them on stack or in heap. In your example, `point` returns the address of `y`, so `y` escapes `point`. Because of that, `y` is allocated in heap, not on the stack.

Unlike C/C++, it is perfectly fine to return stack variables from functions. A lot of constructor-like functions are written as:

```
func NewStruct() *Struct {
  return &Struct{}
}
```

This allocates a struct in heap, and returns a pointer to that.